# Sorting and running functions

Tags: arrays, sorting

I was given a question where I needed to check if in the given array, there's a value where the power of it existed in the array.
For example: the array - `A { 4,16,3,2,15,7 }`
It'll return True because `4^2 = 16`, and 16 is in the array.

1. I know I need first to sort the array but I am not sure what to do next if I want to make it as efficient as possible. Should I run the check inside the sorting code or once it finish sorting?
2. Should I use Bubble Sort? Which sorting method is most efficient for arrays?

Thanks, guys!

Comment: why do you need to sort ?

Comment: I was told I need to sort it in order to have it as efficient as possible.

Comment: @Mor - Sorting is not an efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of sorting, you can use `some` with `includes`.

```js
const arr = [4,8,3,2,15,7];

console.log(arr.some(e => arr.includes(e*2)));
```